# cant POST API status NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]
this my method POST

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {     

            $('#savecus').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo site_url()?>/App5/postNewCustomer",
                type:"POST",
                data: $('#frmaddCustomer').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                  success:function(respon){
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(respon);
                        if(obj.status==200){
                            $('#idproject').val(obj.projectID);
                        }
                            alert(obj.message);
                    }   
                });
                return false;
            });

        });
```

this my controller

```
function postNewCustomer(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cbproject','qCustomerType','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtnamecustomer','customerName','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtaddress','customerAddress','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtphone','customerPhone','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','customerEmail','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtpicname','customerPICName','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtmobilephone','customerMobilePhone','required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE) {

        $data = array(

        'qCustomerType'      => $this->input->post('cbproject'),
        'customerName'       => $this->input->post('txtnamecustomer'),
        'customerAddress'    => $this->input->post('txtaddress'),
        'customerPhone'      => $this->input->post('txtphone'), 
        'customerEmail'      => $this->input->post('email'),
        'customerPICName'    => $this->input->post('txtpicname'),
        'customerMobilePhone'=> $this->input->post('txtmobilephone'),



                );
        $data = json_encode($data);
        $this->curl->http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $this->curl->http_header('Client-Service','frontend-client');
        $this->curl->http_header('Auth-Key','seaweed');
        $result =  $this->curl->simple_post($this->API.'/addCustomer', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10)); 
        $resp = json_decode($result);
        $output= $resp;

    }else{
        $result = validation_errors();
        $output['code']=400;
        $output['message']=$result;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

> error
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
>       at Object.success (eval at globalEval (jQuery.js:2), :23:14)
>       at i (eval at globalEval (jQuery.js:2), :2:27151)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at globalEval (jQuery.js:2), :2:27914)
>       at z (eval at globalEval (jQuery.js:2), :4:12120)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.eval (eval at globalEval (jQuery.js:2), :4:15680)

Comment: does that mean that at line `var obj = $.parseJSON(respon);` the value of `obj` is null? What is the exact value of `respon` before you try to parse it? Is the issue because `$result =  $this->curl->simple_post(...` sets `$result` to null?

Comment: What is the value of `respon`? Can you log it and add it to the question?

Comment: well you should not be calling `parseJSON` when I assume you are returning JSON from the server. `console.log(respon)` is what?